# How to make JavaDoc work with line comments?

Tags: java, javadoc

Can JavaDoc be configured so that it works on `/// …` comments instead of `/** … */`?

I really don’t like block comments (especially non-nesting ones) and I’d rather jump through 100 hoops and hurdles than to just use them.

Comment: What do you mean with *especially non-nesting ones*?

Comment: If you don't like block comments, then find a documentation tool *other than javadoc* that allows you to generate documentation pages from single line comments. I don't know if that exists for Java...

Comment: ... if not, you can write your own

Comment: You can't, and contrary to the suggestions by the previous comments, you should not try to use something else or roll your own. Javadoc is **the** standard for writing documentation of Java classes. Using something is only bound to make your code/project less accessible and confusing for other Java programmers coming on.

Comment: @Jens `/* */` in Java, C, C++ and some other languages don’t nest (i.e. `/* a /* b */ c */` is not a comment, but there are block comment syntaxes in some languages that do nest. Those aren’t as horrible. You can’t use non-nesting block comments to comment out a bunch of code if that code happens to contain such a block comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, Javadoc is created by following a particular semantics and that is why the [*javadoc*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/specs/man/javadoc.html) tool doesn't detect the `//` comments, rather it works with `/** */`.

Comment: The compiler is not involved, it is the `javadoc` tool (I have edited your answer accordingly).